# Position a button without using fixed

Tags: html, css

I have a div `content` inside the div `main`. `content` contains a table, which contents will be loaded from a database. So the tables' width may differ.
Just under the 2nd column of the table I want to place a button. So the buttons' position should automatically be adjusted.

Currently, I solved it with a fixed position, but I would like to avoid using `fixed`, as the column widths may change. Also, the layout wouldn't be "responsible" this way.

This is my approach:

```
<style>
    div{
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    #main{
        height: 500px;
    }
    #content{
        overflow: auto;
        height: 200px;
    }
    table, tr, td{
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    button{
        position: fixed;
        left: 80px;
    }
</style>
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <table>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button>OK</button>
</div>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: DIV]

Here is a https://jsfiddle.net/p58d731e/1/

Is there a better way?

Comment: this might help http://jsfiddle.net/Gabriel_Mendez/T2pmq/

Comment: Is the number of `td` fixed ...?

Comment: @MoidMohd: Yes, it is.

Comment: Can you edit the contents of the table? If so, you could add another row at the bottom, with the second td of that row containing your button. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/p58d731e/2/

Comment: @FreemanLambda: Can I make the last line always be visible? So that the button can be clicked, without scrolling down.

Comment: I cannot think of any way to achieve that sticky behavior without using javascript.

Comment: @FreemanLambda: JS and jQuery would be fine.

Comment: Checkout this fiddle. I gave the button position absolute, .container position relative to host the button. Note that the button has a top property of 215, which is the container's height + 15. The left positioning is calculated by the first column's width + 20, to make up for borders and paddings. https://jsfiddle.net/p58d731e/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery and make something like this

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkczs9yL/)

```
var position = $( ".column2" ).position();
$("button").css("left", position.left);
```

So the left-position will always be that of the start of the second column, even when the left column would be wider. Like [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/77m0ay4e/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code this might help you.

```
table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    button {
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: block;
    }
```

```css
 div {
   border: 1px solid;
 }
 #main {
   height: 500px;
 }
 #content {
   overflow: auto;
   height: 200px;
 }
 table,
 tr,
 td {
   border: 1px solid;
 }
 table {
   width: 100%;
 }
 button {
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button>OK</button>
</div>
```

The button will always be in center.

Answer (score 0):

please use below css and remove position from button

```
button { display: table; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: But what if the content of the table, coming from a database, is wider than only 50px?

Comment: @Dhaval Patel: The OP was quite clear: "start of second column" no guarntee that both columns are of same width.

Answer (score 0):

To track the dynamic size of the columns you should
put the button into an additional row and make this row borderless (and any other properties deviating from the table ones.

```
<tr class="buttonrow"><td/><td><button>OK<button></td></td>
```

(providing aproper "buttonrow" style with your styles).

Comment: Can I make this line be fixed and always at the bottom?

Comment: Long ago I did something like what you intend. So, yes it is possible. But admittedly I used some external input and I do not have access to this right now. I seem to remember it has not been a CSS only solution but involved some js. So hopefully somebody else might know how to keep parts of table at fixed positions relative to some reference. Sorry can't help with this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.[**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/GCr88f2PGu96eI8bwxdE?p=preview)
it is with position absolute and the button is everytime in the second row like you want it. independently from the content of the first row

css

```
th{
position:absolute;
top:210px;
background:#111;
color:#fff;
}
tr{

}
td{
    background:#ddd;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px;
}

#hide{
  visibility:hidden;
}

div {
      border: 1px solid;
    }

    #main {
      height: 500px;
    }

    #content {
      overflow: auto;
      height: 200px;
    }
```

html

```
<tr>
    <td id="hide"></td>
    <th><button>OK</button></th>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin:

```
button {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

Or you can add button to table:

```
<tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><button >OK</button></td>
      </tr>
```